# Laravel custom permission rules - gates, policies or custom code

Tags: laravel, permissions, authorization

I have an API that is being gradually built up to include all of the important business logic and behaviour for my platform. I need to allow or disallow certain actions, but not based on the identity of the user trying to complete the action. I'm trying to identify the best pattern for implementing this logic.

All of my actions are performed by various service classes, that live in the app/Service directory. For example - *EventService* class is responsible for all actions that relate to an event record. A use case here might be that as part of an API call to *cancelEvent(Event $event)* there must first be a check to make sure no-oine has registered onto the event - if they have, this is disallowed.

What would be the best solution here? It seems to me like **Gates** and **Policies** are more about authorising particular users to see if they may perform the requested action. Should I build the 'checks and balances' right into the service class, and prevent actions there? Or is it ok to create policies (that I can then reuse elsewehere) that don't care about the user record, and perhaps check these at controller level instead? Or is there another pattern that I haven't thought of? I have seen people write this into eloquent models too, but that doesn't really feel like the right place to me.

Important here is also the ability to return informative responses in the event of denial. For example *"This event cannot be cancelled because there are 2 users registered"*. This would be returned to the api caller to be fed back to the end user.

Is there a 'Laravel way' of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Policies could work as the foundation for what you are describing and would be a Laravel Way (given they say as much in the [Authorization documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization)). Though they are invoked with a user context, that doesn't need to be used inside the policy. Some benefits of policies that I think are valuable to your case:

- You have a single definition that can be used for authorizing a given action.
- Laravel gives you some convenient ways to get to those policies given a user and model.
- You can provide additional context to the policy query.

I think this third point may be how you would get your details on the reason for a policy failure. Though I am very reluctant to pass-by-reference, this may be worth an exception in order to use the policy framework and get the reason context.

Here's a sketch:

**some.blade.php**

```
@can('doSomething', $someModel)
  You can do the thing.
@else
  Sorry, you cannot do the thing.
@endcan
```

**Http/Controllers/SomeController.php**

```
public function doAction() {
    $reason = null;
    if (auth()->user()->can('doSomething', $someModel, $reason)) {
        return 'Done!';
    } else {
        return 'Not done because ' . $reason
    }
}
```

```
class SomeModelPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function doSomething(User $user, SomeModel $someModel, string &$reason = null): bool
    {
        if ($someModel->hasSomeState()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $reason = 'SomeModel does not have some state';
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

One thing to consider is that you still need definitions of those rules you are validating, like my `$someModel->hasSomeState()`, and you probably want to encapsulate those on a model in order to have a single, clear business rule being invoked (though an action could require checking multiple rules). This is kind of like the idea of "skinny controllers, fat models". Skinny policies help in the same way.